# How to save data in a xml file form database?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to save data from my database into xml file. I am using asp.net and C#.
The xml file will be save in client pc. I want to do this for faster calculation. 
I will save data in xml file. Then calculation will be performed based on that xml file. 
Or anyone can give me better solution.
Is there any one to help me?

Comment: If you're loading all data to client maybe its better to calculate it when theyre already in memory. IO operations are very expensive and if you save file, data might get outdated very fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use LINQ to XML is an easy way to format data into XML, and then you can send it to client pc.